# Running interactive fish without configuration

Tags: shell, testing, fish

For functional tests of powerline script in a controlled environment I need an option that will make fish not load any configuration files as code from them may spoil the test output. With zsh I would simply write `zsh -f -i`. With bash I would use `bash --noprofile --norc -i`. What should I do with fish?

I would rather prefer to avoid heavy solutions like using virtual machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fish relies on its own configuration files to bootstrap itself, so I'm going to assume you mean "without user-specified configuration files" and not "without any configuration files at all."

Unfortunately there's no equivalently simple option for this. The best hack I can think of is to set the env var XDG_CONFIG_HOME to an empty or non-existent directory, before invoking fish. This will change where fish looks for user-provided config files, and so will fail to load them.

An option to support this directly seems like a reasonable request, useful for tracking down bugs, so I'm keen to add it. If you'd like to [open an issue](http://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/) we'd appreciate it; otherwise I can do it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have not found anything essential for powerline testing in default configuration. Though making fish read only from /usr is good enough. With `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` hack it still reads from `/etc/fish/config.fish`.